# Sequelize - model.update vs instance.update (right way of updating)

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

What is the right way to update row in Sequelize.js?
According to documentation I can do both `model.update` or `instance.update`.

`model.update`- requires only one database call (I think), but its called as "bulk" update what is not good when you have for example hooks.

`instance.update` - you need first find that row, then you can update, so its 2at least 2 calls. Its called as normal single update, not bulk.

I have REST API with CRUD structure. Create can't be done otherwise than `mode.create` and it makes sense. But how about update. What is the RIGHT WAY for updating one row?
Or its just about my needs and it is opinion based question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well is like you say, depends more about your needs. Both ways are correct. Taking from documentation, the first way the [instance.update](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-update)

> This is the same as calling set and then calling save but it only saves the exact values passed to it, making it more atomic and safer.

This is safer to update a record. On your api you can set a `parameter` as a middlaware, so every time you call to `update`, `findById` and `remove` for example, always find first the actual object, and update or destroy it there.

For the second way [model.update](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-update)

> Update multiple instances that match the where options.

So you can just update right away with a `where` condition.

Also remenber that the first options returns the updated object, and the second one returns an array with a number of how many records were chaged.